# Azure Storage Account - Tracking the SAS consumption

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights

I have been searching for a few hours without success if it's possible to track the consumption of a SAS credential on a blob container?

I'm going to give SAS credential to a couple customers and I want to be able to track their usage of their SAS (number of operations, bandwidth usage ...)

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use logs for checking or tracking the SAS usage details by using below KQL query in Logs section as below:

Firstly, go to Storage Account, then click on Logs then execute the below Query:

```
StorageBlobLogs 
| where AuthenticationType contains "SAS"
```

[image]

By using above query, you can get so many number of details about our SAS usage.

The properties that can be achieved by using above query are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/storagebloblogs).

Here you can also set a time period between which you want to check the details.